# Why I am getting error for using jsonb keyword in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, jsonb, laravel-authorization

I'm trying to learn **Laravel Authorization** using following mentioned tutorial:
[Tutorial Link](https://laravel-news.com/authorization-gates).

I'm using mysql database and default collation of the database is utf8mb4_unicode_ci. In **Role**'s Database Migration permissions table data type was **jsonb**. That statement was:

```
$table->jsonb('permissions')->default('{}'); // you can check the tutorial link
```

After giving `php artisan migrate --seed` command, I am getting following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your S
QL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json not null
default '{}', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp ' at line 1 (SQL: create table `roles` (`id` int unsigned
not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `slug` varchar(191) not null, `permissions` json not null
 default '{}', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unic
ode_ci')
```

I want to go through similarly like the mentioned tutorial but stuck here. How can I solve this?

Comment: What's your MariaDB version?

Comment: @Mozammil, I'm using MySQL database. How can I check MariaDB in my Laravel project? It my sound stupid but I really don't aware of it!

Comment: From your error message, you are actually using MariaDB. Not sure how to check the version, but you should easily find out by googling. In any case, json support wasn't added to Maria DB until recently, it seems.